# unable to register onclick event handler

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and trying to play around with it. I want to register an onclick event on the the anchor link and avoid taking it to the next page. To do that I have written the following.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('li > a').onclick = hitme;
        });
        function hitme() {
            alert('You will not be able to go to the next page!!!');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading with JQuery</h1>

<p>This is homepage wireframe!!!</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://google.com">Click me and go to google!!!</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

**update:**

I changed the script from onclick to click but on the page load is taking me to the next page. I tried with event.stopPropogation and event.defaultPropogation but it is not working, here's my updated code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('li > a').get(0).click (function(event){
                hitme();
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });
        })
        function hitme() {
            alert('You will not be able to go to the next page!!!');
        }
</script>
```

What stupidity am i doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.onclick` is a property of DOM objects, not jQuery objects.

Try either of the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('li > a').each(function() { this[0].onclick = hitme; });
});

$(function() {
    $('li > a').click(function() { return hitme(); });
});
```

Comment: did you want `return hitme();` or `return hitme;`?

Answer (score 1):

you can always check jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/click/

```
$(function() {
  $('li > a').onclick = hitme;
});
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li > a').click(function(){
    hitme()
  });
});
```

and then try something like this: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 1):

I think `onclick` is Javascript; the `click()` event is the jQuery specific equivalent:

```
$('li > a').click(hitme);
```

Or, if your function isn't accepted as the parameter argument (for whatever reason):

```
$('li > a').click(function() {
    hitme();
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to return `hitme()`'s result.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Absolutely, but your elaborate edit could have taken care of it for me? ;)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Well, it's a functional difference, not a semantical one, but meh.

Comment: I have updated the question, when I tried to return hitme(), I'm taken to the next page, so I tried with event.stopPropogation, but still its not working :-(

Comment: @tintin: This is not a support site. Sounds like you should pop into our Javascript chatroom for iterative debugging help.

Comment: I was doing $('li > a').get(0) which was trying to register the first link handler, removing .get(0) solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try as following

```
    $(selector).click(function(event){
    //for preventing default behaviour on which click is performed
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

use  jquery live method if you want to register click event on element created on fly

```
    $(selector).live('click',function(event){
    //for preventing default behaviour on which click is performed
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
$('li a').click(function (event) {
 alert('i am clicked and not navigated');
 event.preventDefault();
 return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `$('li > a').click(hitme);`

Comment: jQuery `.click` is a jQuery function call, not a property like this that you should override.

Answer (score -1):

I won't contribute much here, since it's been said already. But for the sake of glory, I suspect the proper syntax should be :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".mytarget").click(function({
                    hitme();
            });
    });
```

Don't forget the document.ready, because if the page is slow to load and some div haven't been loaded yet when an event occur, you might experience bugs.

Also, using li > a is a bad idea, in my humble opinion. Give a class to your target element and stick to it, because :

A) otherwise your code might affect other elements you didn't think of.

B) The way JQuery's reading of the DOM works, here your code is going to look for all "li" in your page, then all li that have an "a" as child. Using a class or even better, an id when you can, will speed up the process, as your class will be directly targeted by jquery, rather than checking all similar elements.